# Failing to understand Sigma Notation

Tags: measure-theory

$$ \sum_{N=1}^k \sum_{\substack{S \subseteq [k]\\ |S| = N}}\prod_{i\in S} \alpha_i \beta_i $$

Can anybody help me understand this sigma notation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You sum, from $N$ going from $1$ to $k$, the (sum, for every subset $S$ of $\{1,\dots,k\}$ containing exactly $N$ elements, of (the product of all $\alpha_i \beta_i$ such that $i$ is an element of this set $S$)).

($[k]$ is sometimes used as a shorthand for the set of integers $\{1,\dots, k\}$. This is not a standard notation, but is quite common in some fields)